# How to select latest added file using Putty

Tags: putty

Every day 2 files are added to a directory, I need to get the latest added file and copy this to a directory for further upload. After this the folder is emptied. I would like to automate this in a batch process.

So far with Putty I only manage to copy the entire directory or manually type the name in the get command. Don't know if this might help but all files start with yyyymmdd1200 or yyyymmdd1600.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How is this related to putty?  To my understanding, this is a shell/scripting issue, in which case it may be useful to know the shell you are using (bash, tcsh, zsh, etc.).  Putty may be the program you use to connect to the system you're using, but I don't know of a way to directly use it to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following:

```
mv `\ls -t *00 | head -1` -t target_directory
```

this will move youngest file ending with `00` to target directory

```
rm *1200 *1600
```

this will clear the directory after moving above file.

Comment: Thanks this works! We have a sftp server so a small workaround is required, your scripts works with a SSH server.